# Kubernetes - Minikube port forward issue

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am a newbie to Kubernetes and trying to install Kubernetes locally on my Mac machine.

I am following the below tutorial on Kubernetes website

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

Now, I am at a step where it tells to deploy simple application in my local cluster. I deployed it. Now when I try to access my service using the following command

```
minikube service hello-minikube
```

It launches the browser. Though the browser never shows the service and keeps hanging at 127.0.0.1.

Due to the above problem, I used to the following command

```
kubectl port-forward service/hello-minikube 7080:8080
```

When i try to launch my browser using http://localhost:7080/

I get error attached in the snapshot which is a connection refused issue.
[image]

Can someone guide me what's going wrong here?

Cheers,

**After the below answer**

I tried both of the commands, but the browser keeps revolving, but the service is never loaded. Here is a snapshot for you

[image]

**YAML File**
[image]

**Added Endpoints**
[image]

**Pods Status**
[image]

**Adding Docker Image[image: Docker Image]**

**Events Command update**
[image: Events command error]

Answer (score 2):

to access your application either use `minikube tunnel` and then access it by one of the endopoints of your servers IPs and and port.

Another option would be to expose your application via a service of type NodePort and then use `minikube service $servicename`

Edit:

just a quick sanity check, can you try running the following commands?

```
$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image nginx --port 80 
$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --name nginx-svc --type NodePort
$ minikube service nginx-svc
```

--> this should open your browser with IP of minikube cluster using the services NodePort and you should see the nginx welcome page

The other way you should be able to access the service is, after creation of deployment and service:

```
$ minukube tunnel nginx-svc 
$ kubectl port-forward $nginx-podname 8080:80
```

--> browsing to localhost:8080 should show nginx welcome page.

Please check if this is how your setup currently behaves. if it doesn't there's a problem in your setup that needs to be further explored. if it does, please share your yaml resources, so we might be able to find the problem

Comment: Both don't help. The server keeps waiting in browser but nothing happens.

Comment: I have updated my real question with the terminal snapshot, after i ran the commands.. both of them don't work.

Comment: can you add the yaml definition of your resources? 
I have recreated it yesterday on minikube with a basic nginx image and it worked. so we might have to dig a little deeper

Comment: Ok i am very new to K8. Where should i locate the YAML file from my local cluster?

Comment: you can use "kubectl get $resourcetype $resourcename -n $namespace -o yaml" you can omit the namespace if it is in your current context. if you are new, its most likely in the default namespace. 

so for example "kubectl get service hello-minikube -o yaml" and "kubectl get deployment hello-minikube -o yaml". 

did you try out the nginx example?

Comment: i just added the YAML file by running the command using Kubectl as you advised in the original question posted. No I have not tried the nginx example. What's the link for it? Just to brief you about my background, i am like a serious newbie to it :) haven't go even Docker experience.

Comment: i have edited the original answer with a few commands to try and get nginx + svc running and accessible in minikube. that's the example i meant. just as a sanity check to see whether it's an issue with kubernetes or maybe something else in your setup. 
can you also try the command "kubectl get endpoints" and add it to your question?

Comment: I have added endpoints to my original question. Now i am gonna try commands as you suggested.

Comment: $ minikube service nginx-svc - this command works and I can see the welcome page. The other two commands regarding port forward and tunnel don't work.

Comment: also to add, if i create any other deployment using the commands you provided for any other service. They don't work at all :) Cheers, thanks for your help

Comment: the problem seems to be in the selectors of your service not finding the pods belonging tothe deployment. or the pods of your deployment are not in a ready state. due to the service not having an endoint they are basically not pointing to anything

Comment: so What is your advice in this case, what should i be looking at?

Comment: check your deployment yaml. it needs to have a label: app=hello-minikube for them to match. also check the status of the pods in your deployment with 'kubectl get pods' and see if they are running. its either not matching selectors or pods not being in a ready state

Comment: so i have checked my YAML file. it has correct label. My pod seems to be a problem. The pod is running as CrashLoopBackOff status for hello-minikube. i deleted the pod. Another pod was automatically created but with same CrashLoopStatus. i have attached the snapshot. Any thoughts?

Comment: ImagePullBackOff indicates that kubernetes is unable to access the image. potential causes: private docker repository, docker pull rate limit, or image is not available on docker. 
can you check the image of the deployment (kubectl describe deployment hello-minikube) and then try "docker pull $imagename-from-deployment" to see if you can pull the image locally?

Comment: i did the command and took the docker image name and then pulled the image locally using docker pull 'imageName' and it was successfully pulled. Then i delete the pod and still the newly created Pod is Crashed Status. thoughts? How come your example worked and not mine?

Comment: you could try deleting on of the hello-kubernetes pods. as it belongs to a deployment, kubernetes will start another one. then use "kubectl get events -w" to check for the ImagePullBackOff and look if there's more information regarding the reason why it fails in there

Comment: seems to be the end point has some authorisation error. thoughts?

Comment: i reckon that this error is consequential error from the failing container. is there anything in the logs of the failing hello-minikube pods?